# Deslocamento de conteúdo da página ao fechar modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, modal, iframe

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao abrir um link em um modal em minha página e fechá-lo o conteúdo da página principal é deslocado para a esquerda, sempre que o modal é aberto e fechado o conteúdo se desloca, não sei porque acontece isso, agradeço a ajuda.

O site é este: http://leituracrista.com/folhetos/doutrinarios/a-cruz-e-a-gloria/

Experimente abrir um link na página acima, por exemplo (1 João 3:5).

Comment: Coloque o código HTML e CSS na pergunta.

Comment: Qual versão do bootstrap? Isso é um bug na classe `modal-open` de uma versão. Vá arquivo bootstrap.css (ou min se tiver usando) @MiguelSilva, procure por: `body.modal-open` é meio grande a aplicação do estilo. Comente o estilo `margin-` que estiver lá

Comment: @LucasCosta boostrap 3.3.7.

Comment: O interessante é que se eu abrir o html localmente não dá problema

Comment: Abrindo o site me parece que você carrega várias vezes `bootstrap.min.css` e duas versões ainda, a 3.3.6 e 3.3.7

Comment: @LucasCosta vou testar, estava usando o css online, vou ter que baixar aqui, isso

Comment: @LucasCosta, vou corrigir isto, obrigado

Comment: @LucasCosta consegui resolver, era a duplicidade de referências para css mesmo, deixei apenas a versão 3.3.7 e funcionou de boa.
Obrigado.
Como faço pra marcar o post como resolvido?

Comment: Você pode responder e marcar sua resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A página estava carregando várias vezes bootstrap.min.css e duas versões
Bastou remover as versões diferentes  e repetidas